# Unix Shell script archive previous month file

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have files that has following format in directory:

```
SLS20160112.001    (20160112 stands for YYYYMMDD)
```

I wish to archive all previous month files, for example:

SLS20160201.001

SLS20150201.001

SLS20160107.001

SLS20160130.001

For the above files listed, i will archive SLS20160107.001 and SLS20160130.001 because from the filename it stamps January.

For the SLS20160201.001 it still remains as i only want to archive previous month file. I can only extract date from the filename, not the mdate or adate.

My current logic is to loop through all files, then get previous month files and then pipe out the filename and tar it. But not sure how to do that part.

```
for file in SLS*; do
   f="${file%.*}"

GET PREVIOUS MONTH FILES AND THEN ECHO

done | tar cvzf SlSBackup_<PREVIOUS_MONTH>.TAR.GZ -T-
```

Comment: Use logrotate instead of homemade scripts for this.

Comment: This question belongs on Unix & Linux, as log rotation is a standard *nix function with existing utilities.

Comment: @CodeGnome i might use this homemade script for other sales files too, not only log.

Comment: most `find` versions support filtering by date. (Often it is not obvious how to do this from the `man` pages), so you may need to post a separate Q to http:unix.stackexchange.com to get that part sorted out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to solve the problem by using a shell script. I do a lot of work on Mac so I use csh/tcsh (default shell for OSX), and my answer will be in csh/tcsh script. You can either translate it to bash (your shell) or you can easily spawn a new shell by just typing`$ tcsh`.

You can write a small shell script which can filter filelist for your desired month.

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set mon_wanted = '01'

foreach file (`ls -1 SLS*.*`)
   set mon = `echo $file | awk '{print substr($0, 8, 2)}'`
   if ($mon != $mon_wanted) continue
   echo -n $file ' '
end
```

Let's say the filename is foo.csh. Make it executable by

```
$ chmod 755 foo.csh
```

Then,

```
$ tar cvzf `foo.csh` > out.tar.gz
```